# pytest.mark.django_db and mock.patch decorator not working together

Tags: python, django, pytest

I'm trying to mock a function on a pytest test and the mock doesn't seem to work at all.

Here's my test

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
@patch('apps.titles.logic.get_similar_titles')
def test_get_recommended_titles_for_results(self, mock_get_similar_titles,
                                            set_up):
    mock_get_similar_titles.return_value = OrderedDict([
        ('uuid-1', 165),
        ('uuid-2', 163),
        ('uuid-6', 135),
    ])
    match_signals = []
    results = get_similar_titles(
        match_signals=match_signals,
        title=set_up['title']
    )

    assert results.items() == mock_get_similar_titles.return_value.items()
```

Is there some compatability issue when using @pytest decorators, or have I made a mistake?

thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a resource for everyone, not just your personal help desk.  Vandalizing your questions hurts future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Working off the top of my head here, but shouldn't that last line read:

```
assert results.items() == mock_get_similar_titles().items()
```

Edit: the docs [seem to suggest so](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.return_value).

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking out the function you are testing. You want to be mocking out the functions or objects that are called/used by the code you are testing,  not the code you're testing itself.